# Cannot unmarshal a collection of xml objects using JAXB and Kotlin

Tags: xml, jaxb, jvm, kotlin

I am trying to deserialize/unmarshal XML that contains a collection of Person elements wrapped in People tag. I am attempting to deserialize this XML in Kotlin using JAXB. Everything compiles and runs without errors but the people collection in my class is always empty. How do I unmarshal this collection?

```
import java.io.StringReader
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Person(
        var name:String = "",
        var age:Int = 0
)

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Report(
        var statusCode:Int = 0,
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "people")
        @XmlElement(name = "person")
        var people:List<Person>? = null
)

val xml = """
<report>
    <statusCode>3</statusCode>
    <people>
        <person>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Alice</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </person>
    </people>
</report>
"""

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val report = JAXB.unmarshal(StringReader(xml), Report::class.java)
    println(report) // Report(statusCode=3, people=[])
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you defined the `XmlAccessType` as `FIELD`, so you should use [site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) to make the annotation annotated on the backing `field`, for example:

```
// v--- annotated on field rather than getter/setter/params
@field:[XmlElementWrapper(name = "people") XmlElement(name = "person")]
var people: List<Person>? = null
```